# General Relativistic Boltzmann Equation Verification

Tags: general-relativity

Let $(M,g)$ be a (pseudo)Riemannian manifold. Define on $TM$ the symplectic 2-form $\omega=dx^\mu\wedge dp_\mu$ and use $g$ to define the pull back $\omega_g=dx^\mu\wedge d(g_{\mu\nu}p^\nu)$. Define $$L=\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}p^\mu p^\nu$$
And the vector field $X_g$ by
$$\iota_{X_g}\omega_g=dL$$
where $\iota$ is the interior product. The solution is 
$$X_g=p^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}-\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^\mu p^\alpha p^\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu}$$
and I wish to verify this. The symplectic form is, using 
$$d=dx^\mu\wedge\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}+dp^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu}$$
$$d(g_{\mu\nu}p^\nu)=dg_{\mu\nu} p^\nu+g_{\mu\nu}dp^\nu=\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\alpha}p^\nu dx^\alpha+g_{\mu\nu}dp^\nu$$
$$\omega_g=\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\alpha}p^\nu dx^\mu\wedge dx^\alpha+g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\wedge dp^\nu=\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\alpha}p^\nu dx^\mu\wedge dx^\alpha$$
the last term vanishes because of symmetry properties. Now the problem is that when I contract $X_g$ and $\omega_g$ I encounter terms like $$dx^\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p^\mu}\right)$$
that I have no clue what to do with. This makes me think I have done something wrong in the above calculation.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My calculation for $dL$ is
$$dL=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^\mu}p^\alpha p^\beta dx^\mu+g_{\mu\nu}p^\mu dp^\nu$$
Curiously, if $g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\wedge dp^\nu\ne 0$, then the following happens when it collides with the first term in $X_g$:
$$g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu\wedge dp^\nu\left(p^\delta\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\delta}\right)=g_{\delta\nu}p^\delta dp^\nu$$
which is a term in $dL$. This makes me think that $\ne 0$ is appropriate and that $dx^\mu\wedge dp^\nu$ is not antisymmetric. Maybe that's just a coincidence and I screwed up somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contract the equation $\iota_X \omega=dL$ with some vector $Y$ to get
$$\omega(X,Y)=Y(L)$$
Let bars denote momentum coordinates. Then expand $Y$ in bundle coordinates as
$$Y=y^\mu\partial_\mu+\bar y^\mu\bar\partial_\mu$$
The left of the first equation is
$$Y(L)=\frac{1}{2}y^\mu p^\alpha p^\beta\partial_\mu g_{\alpha\beta}+\bar y^\mu g_{\mu\nu} p^\nu$$
You  calculate $\omega$ correctly:
$$\omega=\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}p^\nu\,dx^\mu\wedge dx^\alpha+g_{\mu\nu}\,dx^\mu\wedge dp^\nu$$
Now contract with both $X$ and $Y$ to get $Y(L)$ while respecting $dx(\bar\partial)=0$ and $dp(\partial)=0$.

Comment: Nice necro. I had figured it out already, but you did it right, so I'll give you the check.